# how to pass the model data to _layout.cshtml

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am new to .net and I would like to pass the number of rows from cartitem model to _layout page, if `model.cartitem.count()>0 or !=null` will return the `cartitem.count()`, otherwise will be 0. becuase in the share layout page there is cart icon and with the number。 I wish it could be user add item into cart the number will atmomically change, if empty will back to 0. I tried put `@model petshop.cartitem` but failed, seems share file cannot use model like this, I also try to write viewbag in cart controller to pass the count number and layout recieve, but also failed... not sure which is the correct way to doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to pass the model data to _layout.cshtml

You can try to use session to pass the row to appear in _layout page, you can refer to it.

1.Register IHttpContextAccessor and session in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
app.UseSession();
```

2.In the controller, set a session variable:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Photo", 11);
```

3.3.In _layout.cshtml, inject IHttpContextAccessor implementation and use it to get the HttpContext and Session object from that.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
...
@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Photo")
```

result:

[image]